# best way to compare an array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

declaring mArrayTemp

```
struct _ARRAY_DATA
{
    int nCode;
    short sDuration;
    short sCount;
};

_ARRAY_DATA mArrayTemp[400];
```

mArrayReal already contains some data lets copy that

```
for(int i = 0; i < 400, ++i)
{
    mArrayTemp[i].nCode = mArrayReal[i].nCode;
    mArrayTemp[i].sDuration = mArrayReal[i].sDuration;
    mArrayTemp[i].sCount = mArrayReal[i].sCount;
}

//then we do something here
```

for the next stage what is the best efficient way to compare the two arrays `mArrayTemp` and `mArrayReal` to make sure they are still both the same and that nothing has changed during some code?

Comment: Why are using `C array` and not `std::vector`. You would avoid implementing a lot of code, copy, memory management, compare, etc...

Comment: I agree, this can be made VERY easy and clean with a vector

Comment: You may also provide `operator =` and `operator ==` to `_ARRAY_DATA`.

Comment: `_ARRAY_DATA` is technically a reserved name.

Comment: If the data can spuriously change, you have much bigger problems than how to compare them quickly. Otherwise `std::equal` is your friend. (Actually using C++ in general is your friend)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (memcmp(mArrayTemp, mArrayReal, sizeof(mArrayTemp) == 0)
{
    //they have the same values
}
```

Comment: Better make sure that you do not have padding for this solution.

Comment: You can force struct pack value to 1 for the array to avoid any padding.

Answer (score 0):

The `memcmp` is not the *best way* to compare two arrays.  Use [std::equal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).  I especially prefer to use Boost.Range to refer to whole collections nicely, and it provides a form of [equal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/equal.html).

```
if (equal(mArrayTemp, mArrayReal)) { ⋯
```

Don't worry about padding, as the compiler will do the right thing.  It's not an end-run around any type knowledge like memcmp would be.